# How to save params string in function?

Tags: c#, windows, string, parameters

I want to store strings in procedure to use it late, and also want to display which strings are inputed. The code look like this

```
 public static void UseParam(params string[] list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(list[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

...

```
UseParam("1", " two thre", "four");
```

Why that code don't want to display which strings I'm input?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question, not sure what you mean ?

Comment: What _are_ you getting? Errors? Exceptions? Nothing?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, that code shows 3 message boxes with the 3 strings.

Comment: Where are you "input" the strings?

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong with the code, so could you paste your error's here and little bit more of code, so we can see, where you call this from.

Comment: @V4Vendetta I want to store strings inside procedure, but don't know how many strings will have, and don't know which strings will be put inside

Comment: @MichalB. yes form application and instead "1" "two thre" have to textbutton.text add inside, but just want to store those valuew inside procedure

Comment: You usually don't want to store information inside a procedure, how would you get at it again? only by calling the procedure again. Look at making an object which would have the method, and a backing field to store the string[]. Then you would use it from other methods.

Comment: Where do you want to store them? How have you tried to store them? You only display a MessageBox.

Comment: Well I tried what you have posted.  aded your method, then attached UseParam to a button click.  and it gives a messagebox displaying 1 then Two Thre then 4?  not sure I understand the problem

Comment: @Schaliasos let's say that weston told me how to store strings and how to use it, but why messagebox dont want to display strings which is inputet?

Comment: @John The MessageBox displays the strings

Comment: @sleimanjneidi loop which will display messagebox times how many strings have put previous

Comment: John, you really have to learn how to ask questions...It is very difficult to understand what you want. I think I got it now, but still it is not 100% sure...

Comment: @MichalB. thnx man for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I think I understand you.

You need to define a variable in scope for your application. In this case it would be a list of strings (`List<string>`). You have to initialize it within the constructor and then call `.Add(list[i])` inside the procedure. Then you can reuse those strings later on in your application.

Answer (score 1):

If what you say is true.  It sounds to me like you want a global list

just declare above your main form constructor

```
 public list<string> myList=new list<string>()

 public Form1()//main form declaration
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Then you can use it anywhere in your main form.

```
Button1_Click()
{
     MessageBox.Show(myList[0]);
}
```

if you want to use it in multiple forms
add a class to your project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace myNameSpace//use your namespace
{
    public class Tools  //I like the name tools  
    {
        public static myList<string> myList=new list<string>();
    }
}
```

then to use it call

```
Tools.myList.Add("1");
```

or

```
MessageBox.Show(Tools.myList[0]);
```